# Dot Product of Position and Direction Vectors

Tags: vectors, 3d

Assume that we have one normalised 3D vector (D) representing direction and another 3D vector representing a position (P).

How can we calculate the dot product of D and P?

If it was the dot product of two normalised directional vectors, it would just be `one.x * two.x + one.y * two.y + one.z * two.z`.

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is the dot product of two vectors. What it _represents_ depends on what those vectors represent, but the calculation itself is the same. Is there some reason it should be different in this case? What do you expect that dot product to tell you?

Comment: @DavidK, for a 3D game, I'd like to render only things that are within the player's viewing angle, i.e. anything more than 35 degrees either side can be culled. One of my vectors is the direction in which they're facing and the other is a corner of an object - I'd like to see if it's visible to them or not

Comment: If the vector $P$ is a _relative_ position--that is, distance and direction from the player to the corner of the object--this can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same way you did with "one" and "two" $Dx \times Px + Dy \times Py + Dz \times Pz$